# Trying do deal with an object that can be an array or a number

Tags: arrays, swift, swift4, bundle, nsbundle

I am trying to read the value of `UIDeviceFamily` from the `infoDictionary`, like this:

```
if let family = Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["UIDeviceFamily"] {
  if family is Array<Int> {

  }
}
```

According to a 2010 documentation, `UIDeviceFamily` can be a `NSNumber` or an array of `NSNumber`.

Thanks to non existing documentation, I guess that, in Swift, it would be a `Int` or `Array<Int>`.

When I run this code, I get the second `if` to be `true`. So, in my case, `family` is an `Array<Int>`.

This is what I do not understand. If `family` is an `Array<Int>`, the next line after the second `if` could be

```
let firstValue = family.first
```

but that will fail.

How do I extract the values from `family` when it is a an array or a number? Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: "but that will fail" - can you explain what fails?

Comment: Info.plist is immutable at runtime, so you certainly **know** what it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
if let arr =  family as? Array<Int> {
   print(arr)
}
else if let item = family as? Int {
   print(item)
}
```

Comment: ahhhhh brilliant. I was not aware that I could use `if let` with casting!

Comment: @SpaceDog They're two orthogonal and completely unrelated features. `a as? B` conditionally casts `a` of type be to type `B?`, if possible, otherwise returning `nil`. You can use that `B?` in anyway you could use any kind of optional value. Whereas `if let` lets you unwrap optionals, any optionals, not necessarily from `as?`. So likewise, you mix-and-match `as?` with `guard let` and `funcThatReturnsOptional` with `if let`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use a `switch` statement with type-casting patterns:

```
switch Bundle.main.infoDictionary?["UIDeviceFamily"] {
case let intArray as [Int]:
    print(intArray)
case let singleInt as Int:
    print(singleInt)
default:
    break // Something else, or `nil`.
}
```